# two or more canvas elements synched with one video element

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, css

what i want to do is define a hidden HTML5 video element and generate 2 canvas objects showing left and right halves of that video. does someone have an simple example, or any suggestions for this?

Comment: Here's an example of capturing frames of a video and displaying it on a canvas: http://www.sanraul.com/2009/12/17/using-html5-canvas-to-capture-frames-from-a-video/

Comment: You may run into performance problems when doing this in real-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you http://jsfiddle.net/msm595/mK5uQ/12/

Answer (score 0):

[This demo](http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html) takes a HTML5 video element and breaks it up into several pieces.  So you should be able to adapt it for what you want.

Comment: actually what i meant is playing the same video synced with 2 or more canvas elements. thanx for your link brainjam. i'm inspecting it.

Comment: @Volkan, I understand.  The example shows one canvas element that is referencing pieces of the video, but you should be able to adapt that to multiple canvases.